# mutating state in redux-starter-kit's createSlice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I use `createSlice()` from `redux-starter-kit`. It's possible to mutate state in reducers thanks to `immer` under the hood. But they said that there are some restrictions in `immer`. For example, you shouldn't mutate AND return new state from reducers at the same time. So I select to mutate like so
**first attempt**

```js
const testSlice = createSlice({
    initialState: 4,
    reducers:{
        increment: state => {state = state + 1},
        decrement: state => {state = state - 1}
    }});
```

But this code doesn't work. Particulary, when I dispatch increment() or decrement(), I see actions in Redux Dev Tools, but state stays unchanged.
Okay. Let's return new state like so:
**second attempt**

```js
const testSlice = createSlice({
    initialState: 4,
    reducers:{
        increment: state => state + 1,
        decrement: state => state - 1
    }});
```

And this code works as expected.
After all, I've tried this construction
**third attempt**

```js
const testSlice = createSlice({
    initialState: {counter:4},
    reducers:{
        increment: state => {state.counter = state.counter + 1},
        decrement: state => {state.counter = state.counter - 1}
    }});
```

And this also works
The question is - why third works and at the same time first not works?

Answer (score 5):

The reason why first example doesn't work is because you are not mutating state - you are just reassigning the **variable** `state` that you get as the argument to your reducer. In your third attempt, you use state as an object. That object gets passed as the argument to your reducer **by reference** so you can modify its properties. That has nothing to do with redux, it's the way Javascript works.

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding on Damnjan's excellent answer with examples and to also caution that passing by reference ala C++ does not exist in Javascript. **Everything is pass-by-value.**

When passing **primitives** (string, number, bigint, boolean, undefined, and symbol), a copy of the **pointer** is assigned to a local variable inside the function. But when the value is modified, a new value is created because primitives are by-nature immutable and the local pointer is 're-pointed' to this new memory address but not the original.

```js
let test = { a: 0, b: 'foo', c: false };

function modifyPrimitives(a, b, c)
{
    a = a + 1;
    b = 'foo';
    c = true;
}
modifyPrimitives(test.state);

console.log(test); // { a: 0, b: 'foo', c: false }
```

When passing **objects**, the same happens; a copy of the **pointer** to that object is assigned to a local variable. You can modify the nested properties of this object, **BUT** you cannot change the original object to point to another. You only have the local pointer and all you can do is 're-point' that to a new object.

```js
let test = { a: 0, b: 'foo', c: false };

function modifyObject(obj)
{
    obj.a = obj.a + 1;
    obj.b = 'foo';
    obj.c = true;
    
    obj = { wow: 'omgwtfbbq' }; // this won't change the object outside
}
modifyObject(test);

console.log(test); // {a: 1, b: "foo", c: true}
```